# Delete URL Prefix on firebase console

Tags: firebase, url, firebase-hosting, prefix, firebase-dynamic-links

At the beginning, we've linked a custom domain to firebase hosting to create dynamic links using this domain. Today, we want to remove it. Deleting the connected domain from firebase hosting was pretty simple but then it remains in the list of url prefixes in the dynamic links section. There is a delete button but it is disable (I don't know why actually).

[image: Disabled delete button]

Does someone found a solution for that?

Also, I tried to delete a link created before so I hit the archive button but actually the link is still active (just not listed in the list of dynamic links anymore). Does it take time to be "inactive"?

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am also same issue.. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

You have to be project's owner to have the option "Delete URL prefix" available.

Once deleted, URL prefix can't be reused for a month.

Answer (score 3):

As shown bleow, it needs 1 month to be reused

[image: message]